# deepCloneList() method in EntityListImpl in Moqui Framework

Tags: moqui

I am performing simple entity find on an entity in moqui by following code -

```
            <entity-find entity-name="mantle.order.OrderHeader" list="result">
                <select-field field-name="orderId,orderName,entryDate"/>
            </entity-find>
            <log message="${result.deepCloneList()}"/>
```

when i am calling deepCloneList() its giving this result with all fields having null but the selected one, which is obviously its behaviour. like -

```
[[enteredByPartyId:null, salesChannelEnumId:null, orderRevision:null, billingAccountId:null, terminalId:null, recurAutoInvoice:null, originId:null, visitId:null, lastOrderedDate:null, parentOrderId:null, productStoreId:null, orderName:Test Order 1, placedDate:null, remainingSubTotal:null, orderId:100052, lastUpdatedStamp:null, entryDate:null, grandTotal:null, systemMessageRemoteId:null, recurCronExpression:null, externalId:null, completedDate:null, approvedDate:null, processingStatusId:null, currencyUomId:null, statusId:null, originUrl:null, syncStatusId:null, displayId:null, externalRevision:null]]
```

But while going inside the EntityListImpl i tried to log the object which is being returned but that object consisit only selected values. Like this-

```
[[mantle.order.OrderHeader: [orderId:100052, orderName:Test Order 1, entryDate:null]], [mantle.order.OrderHeader: [orderId:100102, orderName:Test Order 2, entryDate:null]], [mantle.order.OrderHeader: [orderId:100255, orderName:Test Order 3, entryDate:null]]]
```

How can i get this record as it is in my flow. Anyone who can help, please?

Comment: How are you logging these results? Depending on how you log EntityValue objects the output will look different, for example using Groovy's built in string converter which uses the Map interface vs calling the toString() method.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll explore it further.